# Xcode autocomplete: <<error type>> while project compiles

Tags: swift, xcode, compiler-errors

[image: trashcode]

Suddenly, Xcode Autocomplete stopped working completely and the only thing I see is `<<error type>>` autocomplete suggestions.

The project compiles and runs on the simulator without any issues.

I tried cleaning the project, manually deleting all the derived data, restarting the computer and making a clean build with no success.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: can you update the question by adding the respective codes. `plan` assign statement.

Comment: Most of times it gives `<<error type>>` when the variable has been wrong assigned, so post the `plan` declaration and assignment.

Comment: Plan is just a variable with an implicitlty unwrapped optional : `let plan: IHateApple!`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue in my case was due to the fact that some files were added to both, the app and the test target at the same time.

Making all files to belong only to either an app or a test target solved the problem.